# css :after and click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My need is to have a watermark on row's table.

I use this code [(link to jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/6YSXC/10/) to have the watermark.
This is working fine, but I have a click function on some `td` element and this is covered by watermark.

How update css to have click and watermark visible. `z-index` is not working :/

Thanks for your help.

Comment: edit with good jsfiddle project link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `pointer-events: none;`  to the watermark. Then it works (http://jsfiddle.net/6YSXC/11/).

Comment: Note that this won't work on IE 10 and less, nor on IE mobile 10.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the `z-index` you need to add `position: relative` then it will works well

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/6YSXC/24/)

```
.click{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution too. But a little bit more complex to implement this in my real table.